# encode Php array to json

Tags: php, json

I want to encode my php array

```
Array ( 
         [0] => Laravel, 
         [1] => hallo  
      )
```

to a `json` array that looks like this

```
{"val":["Laravel","hallo"]}
```

anybody have an idea how i do this?

Comment: I wrote your question in google https://www.google.com/search?q=encode+my+php+array+to+json . It's answered faster than users in this site, only 0.25 seconds.

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array    = array("val"=>$your_array);
$json_str = json_encode($array);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 1):

Use json_encode() for your purpose

```
<?php
 $array = array('Laravel', 'hello');
 $json_encoded_array = json_encode($array);
 var_dump($json_encoded_array)
?>
```

Documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()`, see documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

You need `json_encode`.

```
json_encode($array)
```